# Websphere Liberty AdminCenter login does not work when custom JAAS context is defined

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am new to WebSphere Liberty profile. I am working on 17.0.0.4 version. What I am trying to achieve is to have custom JAAS login setup for the application. The application works fine on WebSphere 8.5.

I have reviewed so many link from IBM Knowledge Center for the same, but got result with either or with JAAS custom login, but not both of them together. With WebSphere 8.5 we are having level of hierarchy to decide which authentication mechanism goes where, but with Liberty if I setup Custom JAAS authentication mechanism then I can't login to WebSphere Liberty AdminCenter, and if I configure server.xml for , then it does not authenticate my application's user (because it is designed to get authenticate users via JAAS).

Here is my server.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <server description="new server">

     <!-- Enable features -->
     <featureManager>
         <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
         <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
         <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
         <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
     </featureManager>

     <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="WASLiberty" />

     <!-- Admin Center username/password -->
     <!--<quickStartSecurity userName="admin" userPassword="admin123" />-->
     <!-- Define an Administrator and non-Administrator -->
    <basicRegistry id="basic">
       <user name="admin" password="{xor}PjsyNjFubWw=" /> <!-- Encoded version of "admin123" -->
       <user name="nonadmin" password="nonadmin123" />
    </basicRegistry>

    <!-- Assign 'admin' to Administrator -->
    <administrator-role>
       <user>admin</user>
    </administrator-role>

     <!-- JNDI Connection configuration -->
     <dataSource id="MY_CUSTOM_DS" jndiName="jdbc/MY_CUSTOM_DS">
         <jdbcDriver libraryRef="sqlserverjdbc"/>
         <properties.microsoft.sqlserver databaseName="mydb" 
                                         serverName="localhost" portNumber="1433"
                                         user="sa" password="root" />
     </dataSource>

     <!-- JDBC Driver file location -->
     <library id="sqlserverjdbc">
         <file name="${wlp.install.dir}/lib/sqljdbc4.jar"/>
     </library>
     <library id="MyLoginModuleLib">
         <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="custom_auth.jar"/>
     </library> 

     <!-- JAAS Login Module for web application -->
     <jaasLoginModule id="myCustom" 
                      className="com.kana.auth.websphere.MyLoginModule" 
                      controlFlag="REQUIRED" libraryRef="MyLoginModuleLib">
         <options myOption1="value1" myOption2="value2"/>
     </jaasLoginModule>

     <!-- JAAS Login Context -->
     <jaasLoginContextEntry id="system.WEB_INBOUND" name="system.WEB_INBOUND" 
                  loginModuleRef="myCustom, hashtable, userNameAndPassword, certificate, token"  />

     <!-- To access this server from a remote client add a host attribute to the following element, e.g. host="*" -->
     <httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
                   host="*"
                   httpPort="9080"
                   httpsPort="9443" />

     <webApplication contextRoot="mywebapp" location="mywebapp.war" />

     <!-- Automatically expand WAR files and EAR files -->
     <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

     <!-- Enable remote file access -->
     <remoteFileAccess>
        <writeDir>${server.config.dir}</writeDir>
     </remoteFileAccess>
 </server>
```

Can anyone please point out where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many many thanks **Ut Le** for providing solution.

From the log file, found that the root cause was ClassNotFound exception. It does not have class which I was pointing to from `<jaasLoginModule>`. Later on found that I was pointing to jar file which is not at that location. So that was a silly mistake I made for configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom JAAS login module, then your custom JAAS login module need to ignore the admin center authentication and let the default login modules handle it. 
The better option is to use custom TAI to handle application authentication and let the default login modules handle the admin center authentication.

Regards,
Ut Le

Comment: Thank for the reply Ut Le. How to let Liberty know that which request should go to which authentication mechanism and which request should JAAS ignore?

Comment: Hi Parth, If your application programmatic login by calling the loginContext you can pass in the WSServletRequestCallback, then your custom JAAS login module can get the URL from the WSServletRequestCallback. Also, if your application programmatic login by calling the loginContext, you can set  up a different jaasLoginContextEntry. I think you are better of to use the TAI to handle the application authentication since you will get the request URL all scenarios. Here is the link

Comment: Here is the TAI link https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twlp_dev_custom_tai.html

Comment: I did designed a custom TAI and packaged into same jar as JAAS Login module. Here is the configuration of TAI: `<trustAssociation id="myTrustAssociation" invokeForUnprotectedURI="false" failOverToAppAuthType="false"> <interceptors id="connectTAI" enabled="true"  className="com.test.auth.websphere.MyLoginModuleTAI" 
  invokeBeforeSSO="false" invokeAfterSSO="false" libraryRef="LoginModuleLib">  <properties prop1="value1" prop2="value2"/> <library id="LoginModuleLib"> <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="my_custom_auth.jar"/> </library> </interceptors>  </trustAssociation>`

Comment: But this always throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for `MyLoginModuleTAI` class under ffdc directory. Have followed all steps mentioned in the link specified. But when JAAS LoginModule configuration is in use then there is no such error for class `MyLoginModule`. Any idea what is wrong with `MyLoginModuleTAI` class?

Comment: There is another setup I've tried: `<trustAssociation id="myTrustAssociation" invokeForUnprotectedURI="false" failOverToAppAuthType="false">
 <interceptors id="connectTAI" enabled="true" className="com.test.auth.websphere.MyLoginModuleTAI" 
      invokeBeforeSSO="false" invokeAfterSSO="false" libraryRef="LoginModuleLib"> 
  <properties prop1="value1" prop2="value2"/>
 </interceptors> 
</trustAssociation>
<library id="LoginModuleLib"> <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="my_custom_auth.jar"/></library>`. But this one also throws same error. (notice placement of <library> tag)

Comment: Can you use the second set up and change invokeAfterSSO="false" to invokeAfterSSO="true".

Comment: Changed `invokeAfterSSO` flag to `true`. It throws exception in messages.log file. `An FFDC Incident has been created: "java.lang.NullPointerException com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.internal.TAIAuthenticator 138" at ffdc_18.02.20_21.03.01.0.log`. Corresponding entry have stack dump: `Stack Dump = java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.internal.TAIAuthenticator.authenticate(TAIAuthenticator.java:116)`. And UI shows 403 error: `Error 403: AuthenticationFailed`

Comment: Can you turn on the trace by adding the logging element in the server.xml file: <logging  traceSpecification="com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.*=all:com.ibm.ws.security.*=all"
traceFileName="trace.log"
maxFileSize="20"
maxFiles="5"
traceFormat="BASIC" />
Please recreate it and send me the server.xml, trace.log and your custom TAI code. Thanks